# Use of the Manipulate Flame psy power as a reaction to incoming flame?

Tags: dark-heresy-2e

Manipulate flame usually allows you to extinguish or manipulate flame up to a number of metres equal to the psy rating used on the power. This seems like it would be ripe to be used as a reaction to incoming flame weapons, with the fire appearing to part around the psyker as the flame either gets moved or extinguished before it could reach them.

Would you allow this? Are there any rules that can be looked at as an example of regular actions being used as reactions?

Answer (score 1):

A good example of a regular Action being sorta used as a Reaction is the "Delay" action. You can find it on page 221 of the Dark Heresy 2nd Ed. Core Rulebook.

> Delay
>
> Type: Full Action
>
> Subtype: Miscellaneous
>
> Instead of acting hastily, the character waits for a better opportunity. When he chooses Delay, his turn immediately ends. At any time before the start of his next turn, the character can perform a Half Action of his choice - even though it is not currently his turn. This later counts as being part of his turn, though. [cont...]

If your psyker has time to know the fire is coming (at least 1 Round's notice) you could pick Delay and then use Manipulate Flame as your action. It would not count as a Reaction under this circumstance. Note, however, that this lets the character keep their Reaction, meaning they can still try to do something else, such as Dodge or Parry.

> Would you allow this?

I would probably allow this as a GM: the power in question is incredibly situational and relevant to being shot at with fire. So, it's a clever use of the spell, which should be rewarded, but it's potentially game-breaking to allow psykers to use powers as Reactions. I would also probably explain that this usage is unique and make sure it isn't abused in the future.